# RSA encryption issues java

Tags: java, rsa

I am working on an encrypted chat, I nearly have it but something keeps going wrong with the sending of the information ... 2 characters keep getting added and I dont know why ... when I try and remove two characters which dont exist it gives me a "must start with a 0" error...

if anyone can help me it would be great ... at the moment only the server encrypts data and the client decrypts (save time)... Please explain with examples :)

This is **chatServer.java**

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.awt.*;          
import java.awt.event.*;    

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.swing.*;       
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class chatServer extends SwingChatGUI
{
    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;
    BufferedReader stdin;
    String inputLine, outputLine;
    public ButtonHandler bHandler = new ButtonHandler();
    int stage = 1;
    private static BigInteger l;
    private static BigInteger m;
    PublicKey pubKey;

    public chatServer (String title)
    {
        super (title);
        bHandler = new ButtonHandler ();
        sendButton.addActionListener (bHandler);
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {
            outputLine = txArea.getText ();
            System.out.println ("Server > " + outputLine);
            encrypt();
            out.println (outputLine);
        }
    }

    public void run () throws IOException
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket (4444);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println ("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
            System.exit (1);
        }

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try
        {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept ();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println ("Accept failed.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        out = new PrintWriter (clientSocket.getOutputStream (), true);
        in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (clientSocket.getInputStream ()));
        //stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

        out.println ("Welcome to the Chat Server\n");

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine ()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println ("Server < " + inputLine);
            rxArea.setText (inputLine);

            if (stage == 1)
            {
                String[] parts = inputLine.split("!e! ", 2);
                String string1 = parts[0];
                String string2 = parts[1];


                String j = string1.replace("!m! ", "");


                m = new BigInteger(j);
                l = new BigInteger(string2);

                RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, l);
                KeyFactory fact;
                try {
                    fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                     pubKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
               stage++;
            }


        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }

    public void encrypt() {

        byte[] src = outputLine.getBytes();
         Cipher cipher;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
              cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
              byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(src);
              outputLine = new String(cipherData);
              int count = outputLine.length();
              System.out.println("bytes: " + count);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) //throws IOException
    {

        chatServer f = new chatServer ("Chat Server Program");

        f.pack ();
        f.show ();
        try
        {
            f.run ();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: to host.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
}
```

> this is **chatClient.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;    

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.swing.*;       
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;

public class chatClient extends SwingChatGUI
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static Socket socket = null;
    static PrintWriter out = null;
    static BufferedReader in = null;
    public ButtonHandler bHandler;
    static PublicKey publicKey;
    static PrivateKey privateKey;
    String fromServer;
    int stage = 0;

    public chatClient (String title)
    {
        super (title);
        bHandler = new ButtonHandler();
        sendButton.addActionListener( bHandler );
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {
            String outputLine;
            outputLine = txArea.getText ();
            System.out.println ("Client > " + outputLine);
            out.println (outputLine);
        }
    }

    public void decrypt() {


         Cipher cipher1;
        try {

            //fromServer = fromServer.substring(0, fromServer.length() - 2);
            int count = fromServer.length();
            System.out.println("the length is " +count);
            byte[] src = fromServer.getBytes();
            cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
              cipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
              byte[] cipherData1 = cipher1.doFinal(src);
              System.out.println("encrypted?" + new String(cipherData1));



        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public void run () throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            socket = new Socket ("localhost", 4444);
            out = new PrintWriter (socket.getOutputStream (), true);
            in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream ()));
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.err.println ("Don't know about host: to host.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println ("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: to host.");
            System.exit (1);
        }


        kp();
        CharArrayWriter os = new CharArrayWriter();
        char[] buf = new char[4096];
        int read;
        while ((read=in.read(buf, 0, 4096)) > 0) {
          System.out.println("x");
                 os.write(buf, 0, read);
          fromServer = os.toString();

            if (stage > 2)
            {
                decrypt();
            }
            stage++;
            System.out.println ("Client <  " + fromServer);
            rxArea.setText (fromServer);
            os.reset();
            if (fromServer.equals ("Bye.")) break;
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        chatClient f = new chatClient ("Chat Client Program");

        f.pack ();
        f.show ();
        try
        {
            f.run ();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: to host.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }


    public static void kp() {

        KeyPairGenerator kpg;

            try {
                kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
                kpg.initialize(2048);
                KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
                publicKey = kp.getPublic();
                privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
                KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                RSAPublicKeySpec pub;

                    pub = fact.getKeySpec(kp.getPublic(),
                          RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
                    out.println("!m! " + pub.getModulus() + "!e! " + pub.getPublicExponent());
                } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();






            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




    }



}
```

> this is the GUI ... **SwingChatGUI.java**

```
    import java.awt.*;          
import java.awt.event.*;    
import javax.swing.*;       
import javax.swing.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class SwingChatGUI extends JFrame
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JButton sendButton; 

    public static JTextArea txArea;

    public static JTextArea rxArea;

    public Container container;

    public JPanel n1, s1;


    public SwingChatGUI (String title)
    {
        super (title);

        container = getContentPane();             
        container.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

        txArea = new JTextArea (6, 40);

        rxArea = new JTextArea (6, 40);

        sendButton = new JButton ("Send");


        container.add (rxArea);
        container.add (txArea);
        container.add (sendButton);

    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Frame f = new SwingChatGUI ("Chat Program");
        f.pack ();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The String you're creating with cipherData is gibberish. You should be sending the encrypted bytes over the wire, and decrypting on the other side before attempting to create a String from those bytes. When you call getBytes on a String, the byte array is created with an encoding which you should specify (otherwise it could be anything). Most likely it's utf-8 by default, and the Byte Order Mark is being prepended to the content.

Comment: ok thats cool, but what do I do about receiving it? it gets sent and recevied it will be converted to a string as soon as it comes in the wire ... converting a byted string will just be crazy

Comment: send bytes and receive bytes with byte streams. Don't use Writers and Readers. cipher bytes cannot be used to form valid Strings.

Comment: any tutorials you can link me to for byte streams with sockets ?